# Publish a .war directly from eclipse to a remote web server (FTP, SSH)

Tags: java, eclipse, war, web-deployment

I need  publish a .war directly from eclipse to a remote web server.

Access available via SSH/FTP

is there plugin/ preferred method for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to create and publish a war file directly from eclipse to a webserver you have to do following changes in build.xml file. First create a war file.

```
<!-- Create Jar File -->
    <target name="buildJar" depends="build">
        <jar destfile="${jarDir}/${jarFile}" basedir="${jarClassdir}">
            <zipfileset dir="${base.dir}" prefix="META-INF" includes="weblogic-ejb-jar.xml" />
        </jar>
    </target>

    <!-- Create War File -->
    <target name="buildWar" depends="buildJar">
        <war destfile="${warDir}/${warFile}" webxml="${web}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web}" />
            <classes dir="${warClassdir}" />
        </war>
    </target>
```

Now add following code to deploy it automatically on the server

```
<target name="deploy" depends="undeploy">
        <echo>Deploying...</echo>
        <wldeploy action="deploy" name="${deploy.name}" source="${deploy.source}" user="${wls.username}" 
            nostage="true" password="${wls.password}" verbose="true" adminurl="t3://${wls.hostname}:${wls.port}" targets="${deploy.target}" />
    </target>
```

Here you have to provide username, password and all the required fields and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For uploading a war file directly to the dedicated server, you can refer to [JSch Library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) . By using this, you can directly upload files using ssh.